# ember model array and computed properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Say I have the following:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

    analyses: DS.hasMany('analysis', { async: true }),

    requiresAuth: Ember.computed.equal('analyses.@each.requiresAuth', true),

    isAdjusted: Ember.computed.equal('analyses.@each.isAdjusted', true)

});
```

The idea is that I can query the top level model to see if any of the child `analysis` models have `isAdjusted` or `requiresAuth`

it's not working - hence the question - am I asking too much of ember data + computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use that dependent key syntax for `Ember.computed.X` macros, so the current code you have doesn't do what you're expecting.

I suggest doing the logic yourself like this:

```
Ember.computed('analyses.@each.requiresAuth', function() {
  return this.get('analyses').any(item => item.get('requiresAuth'));
});
```